# How to get html attribute value from a string in swift

Tags: html, ios, swift, parsing

I'm new to swift and need a little help.

I will like to get the src value from an img tag that has been converted to a string using

```
string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
```

I am retrieving posts from a blog and trying to get the image url from each item, so that I can retrieve the image and display it in an image view.

Here is my code:

class myTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSXMLParserDelegate {

```
var parser: NSXMLParser = NSXMLParser()
var blogPosts: [BlogPost] = []
var postTitle: String = String()
var eName: String = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://myurl.com")!
    parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url)!
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
    eName = elementName
    if elementName == "item" {
        postTitle = String()
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    let data = string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
    if (!data.isEmpty) {
        if eName == "title" {
            postTitle += data
        } else if eName == "content:encoded" {
            //get the img src from data

        }
    }
}
```

The Blogpost class:

class BlogPost {

```
var postTitle: String = String()
```

}

Comment: if it is in xml format, then you should go with xml parser, since predicates and other string functions will fail to fullfill your requirements, if there is any thing nested in xml.

Comment: I'm using NSXMLParser to get the contents from a url and implementing the NSXMLParserDelegate methods... When I get the contents, its in html tags. I want to get the img src attribute value from the first image in the feed

Comment: post some related to please.

Comment: I've added my code to the original post

Comment: check https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna

Comment: I saw that, but I had issues with implementation

Comment: what do you mean? I want to use NSXMLParser and not other libraries?

Comment: I didn't say I want to use it and not other libraries, I said I am using it already

Answer (score 2):

Since I was able to solve the problem, I can answer my question since it is allowed.

I implemented the Kanna Framework and used doc.at_css("img") to get the image tag, then node["src"]! for the img src value. For more info https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna

Here is my code:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        let data = string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
        if (!data.isEmpty) {
            if eName == "content:encoded" {
                if let doc = Kanna.HTML(html: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                    if let node = doc.at_css("img") {
                        postImageUrl = node["src"]!
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```